# JSONP only working with named callback function

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I have gotten JSONP working with an anonymous function but can't get it to work with a named function.  This code **works** (the alert appears with the correct data):

```
$.getJSON('http://example.com/test.aspx?foo=bar&callback=?',
    function (data) { alert(data.baz) })
```

However this code does **not work** (no alert appears):

```
function dat(data) {
     alert(data.baz)   
}

$.getJSON('http://example.com/test.aspx?foo=bar&callback=dat')
```

Can you explain why the last code does not work?

**EDIT:** I took out a non-relevant example

Comment: Are you sure the last one does not work? It is actually the same as the first one.

Comment: @Felix, you're right... I tried that example again and now it works, so I took it out of the question... but there is still the remaining one that does not work (which I also tested again to be sure)

Comment: @BaroqueBobcat, it's right before the getJSON call, which is in <body><form><div><script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that leaving out the callback is the correct usage (or, at least, I cannot find any documentation that defines what should happen if a callback is not supplied). If you want to use a named function as the callback you can do:

```
function dat(data) {
    alert(data.baz)   
}

$.getJSON('http://example.com/test.aspx?foo=bar&callback=?', dat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to meet jQuery half way with something like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://example.com/test.aspx?foo=bar&callback=?', dat);
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at jquery's ajax code a bit, I think what you want to do is either
do like Dave Ward and Hamish suggest, ie pass in the function. Or, I think you can pass the function's name as a string like this, since it is attached to the window and jquery looks at the [type of the callback for determining behavior](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/jsonp.js#L27).

```
function dat(data) {
    alert(data.baz)   
}

$.getJSON('http://example.com/test.aspx?foo=bar&callback=?', 'dat');
```

Or, you can use [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) which will add the url as a script tag, which is fine for what you are trying to do.

```
function dat(data) {
    alert(data.baz)   
}

$.getScript('http://example.com/test.aspx?foo=bar&callback=dat');
```